# format TextField as you type numbers and grouping

Tags: swiftui, grouping, textfield, number-formatting

I'm having trouble doing something that should be straightforward simple on a good and clean framework, but with SwiftUI is all a big problem.

I simply need a user to be able to type in a TextField, showing only the numPad, and have the numbers automatically grouped as in `3,000,000` as the user types. Also, if the user taps anywhere in the field to correct a mistaken number, the focus should go to the correct tapped place and the user should be able to erase, keep the focus on the same position, and type the new corrected number. Something as simple as that.

Well, there are multiple problems I'm experiencing:

1. If using a formatter, the formatted number will only display after the field loses focus (i.e. it will show as `3000000` and then after losing focus, `3,000,000`). That shouldn't be a great deal of a problem, but if I focus the field again to add more numbers, it ends up typing something like `3,000,000123` and after losing focus it will not recognize anything after the last 0, so it erases `123`. Also, the numPad doesn't have a comma to type it manually.

That's the following case:

```
@State var number: Int = 0

let numberFormatter = {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        numberFormatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
        numberFormatter.groupingSize = 3
        return numberFormatter
    }()

TextField("1000", value: $number, formatter: numberFormatter)
    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
```

2. If using Combine, the moment a user tries to correct a digit in the middle of the number, the focus goes to the end of the field, screwing the user experience and making people angry.

For this, I'm using this code:

```
@State var text: String = ""

TextField("1000", text: $text)
    .keyboardType: .numberPad)
    .onReceive(Just(text)) { _ in formatNumber() }

func formatNumber() {
    if (text.count == 0) {
        return
    }
    let filtered = text.filter { "0123456789".contains($0) }
    let groups: Int = filtered.count / 3
    let remaining: Int = filtered.count % 3
    var res: String = ""
    
    if (remaining > 0) {
        res += filtered.substring(with: 0 ..< remaining)
        res += ","
    }
    for i in 0 ..< groups {
        res += filtered.substring(with: (remaining + i*3) ..< (remaining + (i+1)*3))
        res += ","
    }
    res.removeLast(1)
    text = res
}
```

Is there any clean solution to something as basic as this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the most optimal solution, but one possible solution using `Combine` without losing the cursor position is to check the length of the published value.

Since the cursor moves to the end of the text because you updated your textfield with the subscriber, you can solve this problem by preventing your subscriber from updating the published value when you edit your text in the middle. Since when you edit, you always start by deleting, you can then just check in your subscriber whether the length of new value is shorter than the length of your old value. If it is, then just return.

I tried the following implementation and it works:

```
            .sink { value in 
            
            let filtered = value.filter { "0123456789".contains($0) }
            //check is just an Int saving the length of the old value
            if filtered.count > 3 && filtered.count >= self.check {
                //withCommas is just a formatter
                self.text = String(Int(filtered)!.withCommas())
            }
        
            self.check = filtered.count

        }
```

Note there are also some problems with this implementation:

1. since it will not update when you delete, you may end up with something like this: 123,456,789 and the user deleted "456" to become 123,,789. It won't autocorrect itself. I haven't figured out a way to make the commas autocorrect while keeping the cursor in the same place either.
2. the above implementation force unwrapped optional, which might cause a crash.

Answer (score 0):

I use normally the .onChange Modifier directly attached to the TextField, like

```
TextField("Value:", text: $depotActionWertString)
   .onChange(of: depotActionWertString) { _ in
             let filtered = depotActionWertString.filter {"-0123456789.".contains($0)}
             depotActionWertString = filtered
    } // .onChange
```

It is more compact for the checks of the user input and you may combine it with the .onRecive statement for formatting.

For the first case in simple Versions for displaying text I use often the combination Text with String(format:...., like

```
Text("\(String(format: "%.2f", self._model.wrappedValue.progress * 100)) %")
```

I think its more a style question as to be right ore wrong....

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I think ot doesn't address the problems I'm facing (digit grouping while typing and editing and without losing the cursor position)